# How do you read an XImage object into RGB channels, or display the image?

Tags: c++, x11

I've gotten an XImage object from XGetImage() from a screenshot, but now I don't know what to do with it. I'm using C++. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The next best thing you could do, would be to use `XPutImage()` or use some other [X11 image manipulation](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/utilities/manipulating-images.html) function.

[Here](http://www.sbin.org/doc/Xlib/chapt_06.html) you can find some examples, reading/changing some pixels, as well as a little more about the XImage data structure.

Comment: He should accept this solution. @Christophe my friend and I got the XImage, but the data is rgb, is there anyway to make the data rgba in the XImage.data field? https://github.com/Noitidart/_scratchpad/blob/68f8a9e0002e78d912d341a8b65a38c3564f7ae6/x11%20new%20way%20skel%20non%20jsm.js#L797-L798 Like on GDK systems we have `gdk_pixbuf_add_alpha`: https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/gdk-pixbuf-Utilities.html#gdk-pixbuf-add-alpha

Comment: As far as I know there still is no alpha channel in core X11.  However you may find some solutions in the [X11 rendering extension] (http://www.keithp.com/~keithp/talks/KeithPackardAls2000/index.html) or [other portable alternatives](http://sydney.edu.au/engineering/it/~graphapp/doc/tech/xtrans.html). Your first link presents an interesting apporach.  But does it work with all X11 implementations ?  Personally, I'd rather consider to use a higher level library such as gdk as you suggested or [cairo](http://cairographics.org/)

Comment: Thanks @Christophe Cairo is very interesting idea! I actually tried GDK but this is going int a firefox addon, and the code needs to run from a thread. Running `gdk_pixbuf_get_from_drawable` from another thread it crashes due to the need to run on the main thread. So then I tried with `g_idle_add` but the design of Firefox (addon scope, it works fine from c, but not js-ctypes) is such that it doesnt work with the GTK idle callback, the callback is searched for on the main thread and it crashes as the callback is actually on the thread. Thats why I swithced to xlib in hopes to run on thread.

Comment: My end goal is to get the binary data (as rgba) and drop it onto an HTML5 canvas, as the canvas only accepts rgba. I'm working on adding in the alpha via javascript, however its jacking up the image for some reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31483868/rgb-to-rgba-coming-out-all-dashed